# Настройка uwsgi в связки Python + Flask

Tags: python, flask

Написал простое приложение на Flask возвращающую строку "Hello world". При запуске из консоли прекрасно работает.

Далее создал файл wsgi.py

```
from new_client_data import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

И сделал файл config.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = rncb.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true

plugins = python3
```

Но при запуске:
**uwsgi --ini config.ini**

Получаю ошибки:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math'
```

Не подскажите куда копать?
PS
Полный трейс ошибки:

```
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
from new_client_data import app
File "./new_client_data.py", line 2, in <module>
import datetime
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/datetime.py", line 8, in <module>
import math as _math
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 64, in <module>
import msvcrt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msvcrt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 72, in apport_excepthook
from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from apport.report import Report
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time, io
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 69, in <module>
import _posixsubprocess
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_posixsubprocess'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
from new_client_data import app
File "./new_client_data.py", line 2, in <module>
import datetime
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/datetime.py", line 8, in <module>
import math as _math
```

Comment: в new_client_data поместите импорты в def app

Comment: @Jack_oS с math прокатило, но как быть с msvcrt? Насколько я понимаю это библиотека только под винду, а у меня убунта...

Comment: `msvcrs` доступна только в Windows. проверьте `getch` для Ubuntu.